# Google Conversion Tracking not registering dynamic value

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento-1.7

I've been trying to set up conversion tracking on Magento 1.7. Here is my code for getting the dynamic value and adding it to the success.phtml page:

```
<?php $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
    $order->loadByIncrementID($this->getOrderId());
    $_totalData = $order->getData();
    $_grand = $_totalData['grand_total'];
    $_grand = number_format($_grand, 1, ".", "");
?>
<!-- Google Code for Successful transaction Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = XXXXXXXXXX;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
    var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $_grand; ?>;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXXXXXXXXX/?value=<?php echo $_grand; ?>&amp;label=XXXXXXXXXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

This however does not work, despite having seen the code on the page with the correct value in it and everything. The only time Google actually registers the value is if it 10.0 and set as such in the Settings panel of the specific action in Google Conversions.

Can anybody maybe shed some light on this? Is there anything I might have missed or not set up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using magento build-in Google Analytics function in
System -> Configuration -> Google API -> Google Analytics

if so, then you could just link you google analytics and adwords account (without the need to add any custom code) read more @ http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375435